# Fitting a Curie-Weiss law function with a diverging point to a data

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, fitting, physics

I would like to fit a function to some experimental data such that the extracted value of Curie temperature (Tc) describes the temperature at which the response flattens out to a constant value. However, the expression I am trying to fit does not exist for values above Tc so I'm not able to converge the fit. From literature, I expect this material to have Tc = 353 C. The equation is

P=A/(T-Tc)^B + C

where P is the dependent variable, T is the independent variable, and the rest are fitting parameters. How can I bypass any errors that come up during the fitting process in order to converge the fit? Specifically the error I get is from

`FindFit[data, P[t, A, B, Tc, C], {{A, 3000}, {B, 1}, {Tc, 353}, {C, 20}}, t]`

and it says, "FindFit::nrjnum: The Jacobian is not a matrix of real numbers at {A,B,Tc,C} = {3000.,1.,353.,20.}." I am aware of what this means and I've seen previous posts about it but I'm just asking for general function manipulation advice that is suitable for Mathematica's FindFit.

Here are data points and my guess for the fit. The results from FindFit don't converge.

[image: dataplot]

Comment: As there is not a lot of data, would be nice to have the `data` array so that we can experiment.

Comment: Of course: `{{22, 5 Sqrt[377]}, {75, Sqrt[9687]}, {125, Sqrt[8243]}, {175, Sqrt[
  5767]}, {240, 2 Sqrt[906]}, {275, 28 Sqrt[2]}, {300, Sqrt[
  570]}, {325, Sqrt[345]}, {350, Sqrt[239]}, {375, Sqrt[118]}, {395, 
  Sqrt[107]}}`

Comment: Data of size 11 is too small for a reliable fit.

Comment: Can you please also give the estimated measurement error of each data point?

Comment: I had left out the errorbars for simplicity. But here they are. Averaging over 3 measurements gives these values for the data points: `{{22, 100.641}, {75, 98.3124}, {125, 92.6697}, {175, 77.3606}, {240, 59.8693}, {275, 38.5962}, {300, 23.}, {325, 18.3212}, {350, 14.9108}, {375, 10.9392}, {395, 10.3763}}` and their associated errors are `{32.6261, 6.86022, 19.4442, 13.532, 5.30309, 9.47399, 6.86469, 2.65322, 4.92755, 1.75818, 1.81654}`

Comment: Note that by specifying `Tc` and `B`, this turns into a linear model.  The consequences are that in that case there are explicit formulas for the "best" values for `A` and `C`.  That turns this into an optimization problem for just 2 parameters rather than 4.

Comment: Is the measurement a count (i.e. an integer) rather than a "real" number?  I ask because it appears that you've transformed the response variable with a square root transformation which is the old-fashioned way to deal with Poisson counts.  Maybe Poisson regression would be more appropriate in that case.

Comment: @JimB I'm fairly certain of Tc and B in this case, but in general Tc is the unknown I'm interested in. And yes the actual measurement is a photon count which I've transformed with square root to change from electric field intensity to polarization. I could try the Poisson approach, thanks.